# How do I do parsing in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, list, dictionary

```
post = { sizes: [ { w:100, title="hello"}, {w:200, title="bye"} ] }
```

Suppose I pass that to my Django templates. Now, I want to display the title where width = 200. How can I do that, without doing it the brute-force way:

```
{{ post.sizes.1.title }}
```

I want to do it the parsed way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neat way to do it is with a filter template tag.

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter('titleofwidth')
def titleofwidth(post, width):
    """
    Get the title of a given width of a post.

    Sample usage: {{ post|titleofwidth:200 }}
    """

    for i in post['sizes']:
        if i['w'] == width:
            return i['title']
    return None
```

That should go in a `templatetags` package, say as `postfilters.py`, and `{% load postfilters %}` in your template.

Naturally you could also alter this to give you the correct `sizes` object and so you could do `{% with post|detailsofwidth:200 as postdetails %}{{ postdetails.something }}, {{ postdetails.title }}{% endwith %}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for i in post.sizes %}
    {% if i.w == 200 %}{{ i.title }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```